# How to define Lambda variables to query Redshift over API Gateway

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-redshift, aws-api-gateway

I faced a problem how to set parameters for API Gateway to query Amazon Redshift with Lambda function.

My connection is working properly, but I got all the time full table respond.
I need to define variables, that user can query specific parameters, values and schemas

Can someone suggest an examples how to set it up

My config is:

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python

import psycopg2
import logging
import traceback
import json
from os import environ

query="SELECT * from public"

logger=logging.getLogger()
logger.setLevel(logging.INFO)

def make_connection():
    conn=psycopg2.connect(dbname= 'database', host='redshift-cluster.amazonaws.com',
    port= '5439', user= 'user', password= 'password')
    conn.autocommit=True
    return conn


    def log_err(errmsg):
        logger.error(errmsg)
        return {"body": errmsg , "headers": {}, "statusCode": 400,
        "isBase64Encoded":"false"}

        logger.info("Cold start complete.")

        print('Loading Function')

        def handler(event,context):

            try:
                cnx = make_connection()
                cursor=cnx.cursor()

                try:
                    cursor.execute(query)
                except:
                    return log_err ("ERROR: Cannot execute cursor.\n{}".format(
                    traceback.format_exc()) )

                    try:
                        results_list=[]
                        for result in cursor: results_list.append(result)
                        print(results_list)
                        cursor.close()

                    except:
                        return log_err ("ERROR: Cannot retrieve query data.\n{}".format(
                        traceback.format_exc()))


                        return {"body": str(results_list), "headers": {}, "statusCode": 200,
                        "isBase64Encoded":"false"}


                    except:
                        return log_err("ERROR: Cannot connect to database from handler.\n{}".format(
                        traceback.format_exc()))


                    finally:
                        try:
                            cnx.close()
                        except:
                            pass


                            if __name__== "__main__":
                                handler(None,None)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Rather than using `psycopg2`, I would recommend [Using the Amazon Redshift Data API](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/mgmt/data-api.html). It provides a much easier way to run a query on Amazon Redshift.

First, send the query with [`execute_statement()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html#RedshiftDataAPIService.Client.execute_statement), then retrieve the results with [`get_statement_result()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/redshift-data.html#RedshiftDataAPIService.Client.get_statement_result).